# Create a Panning Slider (React/CSS)

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a container that has 8 elements. I would like to make the 8 elements side by side and pan across the screen when you scroll or drag with touch. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong because if you reversed the overflow it works fine vertically.

Here my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/panning-slider-zdpmh

```js
const appContainerStyle = {
  height: "40vh",
  width: "100%",
  backgroundColor: "black"
};
const appInnerContainerStyle = {
  height: "100%",
  width: "200vw",
  display: "inline-block",
  overflowY: "hidden",
  overflowX: "scroll",
  backgroundColor: "blue"
};
const appBoxContainerStyle = {
  float: "left",
  height: "100%",
  width: "25vw",
  backgroundColor: "red",
  borderRadius: "1vh"
};
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={appContainerStyle}>
      <div style={appInnerContainerStyle}>
        <div style={appBoxContainerStyle}></div>
        <div style={appBoxContainerStyle}></div>
        <div style={appBoxContainerStyle}></div>
        <div style={appBoxContainerStyle}></div>
        <div style={appBoxContainerStyle}></div>
        <div style={appBoxContainerStyle}></div>
        <div style={appBoxContainerStyle}></div>
        <div style={appBoxContainerStyle}></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `float: left`, all the inner boxes will squeeze to be fit in the container.

What you want to do is to preserve the width of the inner boxes in a single row. And then, the total width of the boxes will be larger than the width of the container which finally makes the overflow happen. You could give the inner boxes `minWidth` instead of `width`.

In the demo below, I've showed another approach using flexbox.

Here's the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/panning-slider-forked-ftz18?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The flex-shrink on the children without the float and with flex on the parent container was all I needed! Thanks! Heres  the fixed: https://codesandbox.io/s/panning-slider-zdpmh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I'm glad it helps!